# iOS 12 suggest phone number in QuickType bar

Tags: ios, autofill, ios12

How is Lyft suggesting my phone number in the QuickType bar so that I do not have to enter it manually? I know Apple introduced autofill functionality for usernames, passwords, security codes, and more with iOS 12 and it looks like this phone number suggestion may be using a similar function but I cannot figure out how to get any of my apps to suggest the phone number like Lyft is doing below.

[image: Lyft Enter Phone Number Screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible that it's just looking up the devices contacts?

Comment: There is a property that you set to tell the OS what type of text field it is.

Comment: @CharlieFish what is the property?

Comment: Set the text field's [`textContentType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1649656-textcontenttype) to [`.telephoneNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/1649664-telephonenumber) and you get this behavior.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1649656-textcontenttype

Comment: Even more cool, if you send SMS messages to validate a phone numbers and set the SMS validation code’s `UITextField` text content type to `.phoneNumber`, too, it will automatically pull the verification code from the SMS and presented as an option, too. Really streamlines SMS-based verification workflows.

Comment: Change keyboard property textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad and working fine same as Lyft App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rob said in a comment below my question.

```
textField.textContentType = UITextContentType.telephoneNumber
```

Results in the behavior I was looking for. Thanks @Rob

Comment: `UITextContentType` is redundant  `textField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber`

Comment: textField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber Not working in iOS 14.2

Answer (score 5):

## From Interface Builder / Storyboard

- Select a textField.
- Show the Attributes inspector.

[image: Content Type Telephone Number]

## From Code

You can access this property in any `UITextField`

```
textField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
```

Comment: it is not showing the suggestions for keyboardType set to 'phonePad'.

Answer (score 0):

**Phone number autofill strong solution:**

textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad

textField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber