# How to you auto-fill the mdn in a text field?

Tags: ios

I've been using the iOS 12 SMS code validation text field quick-fill feature within my app for a while.
So I imagined additionally using the phone number auto-fill would be really quick and simple.
But its not, I can't get it to work.

I came across this past question [iOS 12 suggest phone number in QuickType bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857040/ios-12-suggest-phone-number-in-quicktype-bar)

and I'm already doing what it says there - to set text field content type to Telephone Number and to set the text file .textContentType to .telephoneNumber.
But when I make the text field the first responder there's no phone number quick fill number above the keypad.

Like I say, I'm already familiar with this mechanism as I've been using it for SMS quick-fill, so why isn't the telephone quick-fill working?

Comment: Possibly, your simulator has no friends and doesn't have any phone numbers in their contacts.

Comment: This is running on hardware not simulator, but regardless of that what does friends/contacts have to do with anything? This mechanism is for obtaining the device phone number

Comment: ah, sorry, I was trying to make an unfunny joke. I thought the problem may have been that you didn't have any contacts, so it can't quick-fill.

Comment: what is textfield character MaxLimit?